# F# - What is the best way to convert a char[] to a string?

Tags: arrays, string, f#, char

Is there an easy way to convert a char[] to string in F# without explicitly looping over the array? I tried:

```
let char_arr = [|'a','b','c'|]
let str = new String(char_arr)
```

but that doesn't work. Suggestions?

Comment: Elements in F# array are divided by `;` not `,`. You have an array of single tuple element

Comment: @Petr - You should post that as an answer. It might sound simple, but it is the right one!

Comment: @Petr - Sorry, when I wrote my answer, I didn't see your reply. Perhaps I should delete my answer?

Comment: Don't worry. It just a matter of helping people. I'm not here for the reputation or badges :)

Comment: @Petr -  You're absolutely right. Thanks for catching my mistake! The 'new' keyword should work with your correction.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The array elements are separated by ';'

```
let char_arr = [|'a';'b';'c'|]
let str = new string(char_arr)
str |> printfn "%A"
```

Link: http://ideone.com/scp7qb